# How do I download only files that start with a value and end with other values?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use `aws s3 cp s3a://path/to/directory/dt=2019* ./home/directory/ --recursive`. It's on aws obviously but I don't want any parquet files coming from other years like 2017 and 2018 or 2020. I only want data from 2019, which means that the file is going to be `dt=2019` plus `-01-01`, `-01-02` , `-01-03`, ... etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) you need to provide exclude and include arguments:

```
aws s3 cp s3://path/to/directory/ ./home/directory/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "dt=2019*"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out asap.